# How to avoid polynomial roots solution to be in a "power m/n" form?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

How to find complex polynomial roots not in a weird "power m/n" form but in an "a+ib" form (e.g. for x^2+x+1==0)?

Comment: `Solve[x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x] // RootReduce`?

Comment: Or `Solve[x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x] // ComplexExpand`

Answer (score 1):

At least for the OP's specific example:

```
Solve[x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x] // ExpToTrig
   {{x -> -(1/2) - (I Sqrt[3])/2}, {x -> -(1/2) + (I Sqrt[3])/2}}
```

As noted in the comments, `RootReduce[]` works here, because attempting to convert roots of quadratics to a `Root[]` object automatically yields the explicit radical representation. On the other hand, `ComplexExpand[]` and `ExpToTrig[]` work similarly, converting complex-valued exponentials to trigonometric functions, which evaluate immediately in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
Solve[x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x]
```

> {{x -> -(-1)^(1/3)}, {x -> (-1)^(2/3)}}

```
% // N
```

> {{x -> -0.5 - 0.866025 I}, {x -> -0.5 + 0.866025 I}}

Or you can do this in one step using `NSolve` for finding numerical roots,

```
NSolve[x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x]
```

Comment: Bur can't I get the result in a form of: $$\{\{x -> -{1 \over 2} + {\sqrt{3} \over 2}i\},\{x -> -{1 \over 2} - {\sqrt{3} \over 2}i\}\}$$

Comment: @einy Andrew has suggested (`RootReduce`) that in his comment.